# How can I delete the first part of all my rows in a dataset

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I had daily data that I turned into weekly using Excel pivot table. My "Date" Column used to look like : 1/1/2018 but now (the weekly) looks like 1/1/2018 - 1/7/2018. I want to delete the first part from all my rows (200 rows) so that each row shows only 1 date, and that's the later day: 1/7/2018. I know there's replace(); but I want each row to represent different numbers.

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and an appropriate database tag would all help.

Comment: Is this excel or sql and if it’s sql then what database are you using?

Comment: Hi there, welcome to SO! Please take your time to familiarize yourself with the site by taking [the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), reading up on [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), going through [this brilliant question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/), and lastly, understanding how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Additionally, your question lacks your attempt. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This is my wild guess...

```
CREATE TABLE my_table2 (
  my_date varchar(50)
);
INSERT INTO my_table2 (my_date) VALUES ('1/1/2018 - 1/7/2018');
INSERT INTO my_table2 (my_date) VALUES ('12/10/2018 - 12/16/2018');

SET @row_number = 0;

SELECT (@row_number:=@row_number + 1) as date_number
      ,t.my_date
      ,SUBSTRING(t.my_date, LOCATE(' - ',t.my_date,1) + 3, LENGTH(t.my_date) - LOCATE(' - ',t.my_date,1) + 3) as my_alt_date
  FROM my_table2 t;
```

Here is the output...

```
+----+-------------+-------------------------+-------------+
|    | date_number |         my_date         | my_alt_date |
+----+-------------+-------------------------+-------------+
|  1 |           1 | 1/1/2018 - 1/7/2018     | 1/7/2018    |
|  2 |           2 | 12/10/2018 - 12/16/2018 | 12/16/2018  |
+----+-------------+-------------------------+-------------+
```

I created the ASCII table using [this tool](https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/). Hope this helps get you started.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to delete the first part from all my rows (200 rows) so that each row shows only 1 date, and that's the later day: 1/7/2018

You can use a [mysql regular expression](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html) for that.

This :

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('1/1/2018 - 1/7/2018', '.+ - ', '');
```

Yields :

```
1/7/2018
```

Explanation : regular expression `'.+ - '` matches everything from the beginning of the string until the last `-` substring ; `REGEXP_REPLACE` will replace the match part with what is given as third argument (here, an empty string).

You can wrap that in an `UPDATE` query, like :

```
UPDATE my_table SET my_date = REGEXP_REPLACE(my_date, '.* - ', '');
```